# How to show the result of an SBT task in Console

Tags: sbt

In sbt console, it is possible to do `show settingsKey` to view the value of a setting for example:

```
> show resourceManaged
[info] /Users/code/my_project/target/scala-2.11/resource_managed
```

Is there a way to do this for tasks? That is to execute and view the result of a task in the console?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can also print the results of a task in console with `show`. For example `sbt 'show fullClasspath'` or directly `show fullClasspath` in sbt interactive mode.

Remember that [keys are scoped](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Scopes.html#Examples+of+scoped+key+notation):

> Examples of scoped key notation
>
> - fullClasspath specifies just a key, so the default scopes are used: current project, a key-dependent configuration, and global task scope.
> - test:fullClasspath specifies the configuration, so this is fullClasspath in the test configuration, with defaults for the other two scope axes.
> - *:fullClasspath specifies Global for the configuration, rather than the default configuration.
> - doc::fullClasspath specifies the fullClasspath key scoped to the doc task, with the defaults for the project and configuration axes.
> - {file:/home/hp/checkout/hello/}default-aea33a/test:fullClasspath specifies a project, {file:/home/hp/checkout/hello/}default-aea33a, where the project is identified with the build {file:/home/hp/checkout/hello/} and then a project id inside that build default-aea33a. Also specifies configuration test, but leaves the default task axis.
> - {file:/home/hp/checkout/hello/}/test:fullClasspath sets the project axis to “entire build” where the build is {file:/home/hp/checkout/hello/}.
> - {.}/test:fullClasspath sets the project axis to “entire build” where the build is {.}. {.} can be written ThisBuild in Scala code.
> - {file:/home/hp/checkout/hello/}/compile:doc::fullClasspath sets all three scope axes.

You can use `inspect fullClasspath` to see scopes for that task in your project in **Related**.